# Finding inductor current at infinity

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, circuit-analysis, inductor

[image]

Can someone please explain how to go about solving this? I understand how we obtain Vc but when looking for the inductor current at infinity I get confused. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

T->inf means steady state, only DC voltages and currents. So the inductor acts just like a wire. So you have 75R and 25R in parallel above and below this "wire", meaning voltage on it is half of the source. Current flowing to lower 25R is three times higher than that or 75R. And it comes from the upper 75R (all of it) and the upper 25R (whatever remains). So the current on the inductor is twice current on 75R, which is 10V/2/75R=0.067A. And your IL is then 0.14A